# Is there any technique for baking instanced/linked objects, Cycles/BI?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I would like to know is there any technique that I can bake textures of the Instanced or Linked Object meshes in Blender, Cycles or BI?

Comment: If their material is linked, they'll use the same. If you want them to be different, you need to make them single user.

Comment: Thanks, well, i know but i am looking for a workaround, I see engine like unreal can do that, is possible in Blender?

Comment: so you just want to re-bake the textures to the objects instead?

Comment: no, i want every instanced/linked object has unique baked texture on it, like Unity and Unreal engines, example of shadows baked on multiple instances.

Comment: As far as I know, blender lacks support for this, so it's not doable unless you make each instance single user and make a unique material for it.